# Using Rails Composer, getting error "-bash: rails: command not found" using "learn-rails" gemset

Tags: railsapps, nitrous, rails-composer

I'm using Nitrous on Windows 7, and trying to use RailsComposer following "Build ‘Learn Rails’ in Less Than Five Minutes" of the [Learn Ruby on Rails](http://learn-rails.com/learn-ruby-on-rails.html) book.

The book tells:

Use the “learn-rails” gemset we created earlier:

```
$ rvm use ruby-2.1.3@learn-rails
```

and then,

```
$ rails new foobar-kadigan -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb
```

I have this error:

> -bash: rails: command not found

Comment: The book advises to create and use an RVM gemset named "learn-rails", installing Rails in the gemset. Check that the Rails gem is installed in the gemset with "rails -v". If not there, this article will help you install Rails: http://railsapps.github.io/rubyonrails-nitrous-io.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. May all your questions be answered quickly and accurately!

Comment: TY. I see now.                                                        $ rvm use ruby-2.1.5@learn-rails --create
$ gem install rails